# str_match gives challenging output to varying input variable

Tags: r, stringr

I'm using stringr to match swim times, but can't get uniformity for column output of minutes, seconds and fractional seconds.

```
string <- c("3:45.88","24.99")
time <- "[[\\s]+]?([\\d]+)\\:?([\\d]+)\\.([\\d]+)"
```

This is output:

```
str_match(string,time)     
     [,1]      [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "3:45.88" "3"  "45" "88"
[2,] "24.99"   "2"  "4"  "99"
```

This would be desired:

```
     [,1]      [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "3:45.88" "3"  "45" "88"
[2,] "24.99"   ""   "24" "99"
```

Many thanks for any guidance.